# MySQL syntax error when inserting a row into database

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to post a row into a mysql database using data from an express form but always get SQL syntax errors

```
router.post('/add', function(req, res, next) {

  var title = req.body['title'];
  var director = req.body['director'];
  var release = req.body['release'];
  var review = req.body['review'];

  connection.query("INSERT INTO films.filmStore (title, director, review, release) VALUES ('" + title.toString() + "', '" + director.toString() + "', '" + review.toString() + "', '" + release.toString() + "');", function(err, result){
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log("1 record inserted");
  });

  res.redirect('/');
});
```

However I get an error

```
throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'release) VALUES ('Superman', 'Richard Donner', 'One of the best films of all tim' at line 1
```

I've tried everything I can think of but I'm new to SQL and can't  figure out what's different from other examples I've seen.

Comment: Perhaps you would be better using a parameterised query instead of dumping the raw values in (think: SQL injection). Anyhow, the problem is potentially related to your parameters - if one contains a single quote then your query will be broken. Dump your query before sending it to the server to see the issue.

Comment: This article has some helpful advice on using parameterised queries in Node.js: https://blog.stvmlbrn.com/2018/07/27/dynamic-where-clauses-with-parameterized-queries-in-node-mysql.html

Comment: @MartinParkin I Tried this `const query = "INSERT INTO films.filmStore (title, director, review, release) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";

  connection.query(query, [title.toString(), director.toString(), release.toString(), review.toString()], function(err, result){
      if(err) throw err;
      console.log("1 record inserted");
      });` But still getting syntax error whatever I make the parameters

Answer (score 0):

`release` is a reserved keyword in mysql. 
See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html

Either alter the name of that column or use backticks:

```
"INSERT INTO films.filmStore (title, director, review, `release`) VALUES (..."
```